# How do I make my landscape photos larger using my tumblr theme code?

Tags: html, css, tumblr, tumblr-themes, tumblr-html

I know near to nothing about coding, and i'm trying to edit my tumblr theme slightly. I've made it this far and now i'm stuck on something:

If you look on [my blog](http://7iue.tumblr.com), the width of both the landscape and portrait photos are the same. This makes the landscape photos look much smaller than the portrait ones. I am happy with the size of my portrait photos, but i want to make my landscape photos bigger, so they are around the same size as the portrait photos are now, but with landscape orientation of course.

After doing a little research, I found out about `{TagsAsClasses}`, which seems to be a way to edit posts that are tagged with something specific on [Tumblr](https://www.tumblr.com/). So if I tagged something with *"landscape"*, I could change the style of these posts only, which would mean that I could change the max-width of all my landscape photos provided I have tagged them with *"landscape"*.

I want to know if I'm going in the right direction with this and if it is possible for me to do this using tagsasclasses? If so, I would like to know exactly what to paste into my code, and where to paste it, if possible. It would be much appreciated.

Comment: Did you try that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11530132/change-default-photoset-size-on-tumblr

Comment: @pyano i don't think it will work because it is explaining how to change photosets, not individual photos